# Variables plantilla con deducción de argumentos de plantilla y argumentos por defecto

Tags: c++, template

Recientemente he descubierto una característica de las plantillas que desconocía. Es la fusión de diferentes declaraciones de la misma plantilla con diferentes argumentos por defecto en los argumentos de la plantilla, está detallado en el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) (traducción mía):

> #### 17.1 parámetros de plantilla
>
> 10. El conjunto de argumentos de plantilla por defecto disponibles se obtiene fusionando los argumentos por defecto de todas las declaraciones previas de la plantilla de igual forma a como se hace con los argumentos por defecto de funciones [ *Ejemplo:*
>
>     ```
>     template<class T1, class T2 = int> class A;
>     template<class T1 = int, class T2> class A;
>     ```
>
>     es equivalente a
>
>     ```
>     template<class T1 = int, class T2 = int> class A;
>     ```
>
>     — *fin del ejemplo* ]

Así que he decidido probar el ejemplo que menciona el estándar:

```
template <typename T, typename U = int> struct S;
template <typename T = int, typename U> struct S
{ void f() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; } };

int main()
{
    S s; s.f();
    return 0;
}
```

El código anterior muestra `void S<int, int>::f() [T = int, U = int]` cuando se compila con [gcc HEAD 8.0.1 201803](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FRKp6dVJPl680aW6) pero la compilación falla con [clang HEAD 7.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/09pylNj6KWJ9X1UN) a no ser que se usen los paréntesis angulares al instanciar:

```
S s; s.f(); // error: declaration of variable 's' with deduced type 'S' requires an initializer
S<> t; t.f(); // Correcto
```

Dejando de lado este error, he probado este comportamiento en el resto de tipos de plantilla y el código es aceptado o rechazado de manera irregular:

**`Funciones plantilla`**

```
template <typename T, typename U = int> void function();
template <typename T = int, typename U> void function()
{ std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\n'; }

int main()
{
    /* Rechazado por GCC: no matching function for call to 'function()'
       template argument deduction/substitution failed:
       couldn't deduce template parameter 'T'
       mismo error con function<>()

       CLang compila sin problemas. */
    function(); // CLang muestra 'void function() [T = int, U = int]'
    return 0;
}
```

**`Variable plantilla`**

```
template <typename T, typename U = int> int variable;
template <typename T = int, typename U> int variable = 0;

int main()
{
    /* GCC se queja del número de argumentos (0, should be at least 1)
     mientras que CLang se queja de la redefinición de 'variable' */
    std::cout << variable<> << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

**`Alias plantilla`**

```
template <typename T, typename U = int> using alias = int;
template <typename T = int, typename U> using alias = int;

int main()
{
    /* GCC se queja de la redefinición de 'alias'
       mientras que CLang compila sin problemas. */
    alias<> v = 0;
    std::cout << v << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

---

El texto del estándar no diferencia entre tipos de plantillas, así que pensé que todos los tipos se deberían comportar igual.

Aún así, el caso de la variable plantilla es el único rechazado por ambos compiladores, así que tengo algunas dudas sobre este tipo de plantilla. Para mi tiene sentido que CLang rechace la plantilla alegando redefinición mientras que creo que GCC se equivoca al rechazar la plantilla *por motivos erróneos*, pero este razonamiento no sigue lo que el estándar indica en 17.1.10.

Así pues, ¿qué debería esperar en el caso de las variables plantilla?:

- El código es rechazado por redefinición (CLang tiene razón).
- El código es aceptado, fusionando todas las definiciones (tanto GCC como CLang se equivocan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A falta de una explicación mejor lo más acertado que puedo decir es que, desde mi punto de vista, el comportamiento de CLang es el esperado. Me explico:

En C++ no es posible redeclarar variables. Las variables plantillas son, esencia, variables, luego es entendible que tengan que satisfacer las limitaciones impuestas por las variables "*tradicionales*".

En este caso tenemos lo que a todas luces sería una redeclaración:

```
template <typename T, typename U = int> int variable;     // 1a declaracion
template <typename T = int, typename U> int variable = 0; // 2a declaracion
```

Otro cantar sucedería si se tratasen de especializaciones:

```
template <typename T> int variable = 0;
template <> int variable<double> = 2;

int main()
{
    std::cout << variable<int> << ' ' << variable<double> << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Para más inri, después de algunas pruebas, he observado que acompañando la primera declaración con `extern` Clang se calla y compra la solución:

```
template <typename T, typename U = int> extern int variable;
template <typename T = int, typename U> int variable = 0;
```

Lo cual tiene cierto sentido ya que con `extern` no estás declarando una variable en ningún sitio sino que la variable ya tiene que existir. De hecho esta misma solución sería aplicable sin plantillas (aunque entonces carezca totalmente de sentido):

```
extern int variable;
int variable = 0;
```

Comment: Sin embargo, al tratarse de plantillas, cada definición "no existe" hasta que se instancia, así pues no habría re-declaración.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus Lo se... la frase que da inicio a la respuesta no está puesta al azar. He leído todo el tema de plantillas y es la mejor respuesta que puedo dar... la que me parece más coherente. Me da la sensación de que esa parte del estándar no está muy bien detallada y se les ha escapado ese caso